# What is "rename a tag"?

Tags: discussion

In [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), we will see a row named "renames", But I have never found the rename function.

What is "rename a tag"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'rename' counter is the amount of times a suggestion rule was applied. For example, 7,209 questions were changed from [iphone-sdk](/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) to [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) through the synonym system.